# Get current time javascript + 1 hour (minutes bug)

Tags: javascript, time

Hi I currently have a script running that shows the current time + 1 hour, the issue i'm having is that every hour at the first 9 minutes the 0 is not showing up* and somehow I just can't find the solution.

*Example: 9:1am instead of 9:01am

I like Moments.js but in this case I can't use an external library

```js
var now = new Date;
now.setHours(now.getHours() + 1);
var isPM = now.getHours() >= 12,
  isMidday = 12 == now.getHours(),
  result = document.querySelector("#result"),
  time = [now.getHours() - (isPM && !isMidday ? 12 : 0), now.getMinutes() || "00"].join(":") + (isPM ? " pm" : "am");

function addTime(t) {
  for (var s in t) {
    var e = s.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substr(1);
    this["set" + e](this["get" + e]() + t[s])
  }
  return this
}

function showTime(t) {
  var s = function() {
    return this < 10 ? "0" + this : this
  };
  if (t) return [s.call(this.getHours()), s.call(this.getMinutes()), s.call(this.getSeconds())].join(":");
  var e = this.getHours() >= 12,
    i = 12 == this.getHours();
  return time = [s.call(this.getHours() - (e && !i ? 12 : 0)), s.call(this.getMinutes()), s.call(this.getSeconds())].join(":") + (e ? " pm" : " am")
}
result.innerHTML = time;
```

```html
<script>
var today=new Date,dd=today.getDate(),mm=today.getMonth()+1,yyyy=today.getFullYear().toString().substr(-2);dd<10&&(dd="0"+dd),mm<10&&(mm="0"+mm),today=mm+"/"+dd+"/"+yyyy,document.write(today);
</script>
  
<span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a lot of your code isn't actually getting called, it looks like only the lines that influence the output are these:

```
var now = new Date;
now.setHours(now.getHours() + 1);
var isPM = now.getHours() >= 12, isMidday = 12 == now.getHours(), result = document.querySelector("#result"),
time = [now.getHours() - (isPM && !isMidday ? 12 : 0), now.getMinutes() || "00"].join(":") + (isPM ? " pm" : "am");
result.innerHTML = time;
```

The most relevant chunk being:

```
now.getMinutes() || "00"
```

The reason you're getting the un-padded minute in your example is because you're only handling if now.getMinutes() is exactly 0, skipping the 1-9 case. In order to fix this you could simply do this instead:

```
(now.getMinutes() < 10) ? "0" + now.getMinutes() : "" + now.getMinutes()
```

As others have alluded to, formatting dates correctly and doing date arithmetic can be [pretty tricky](https://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time) especially if you're handling things like time zones and different locales. Using a library like [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) is a really good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Not an actual answer to solve the problem in your code, but why don't you use something like https://momentjs.com/ ?

```
var timeToShow = moment().add(1, 'hour').format('h:mma');  //9:02am
```

Comment: actually, it does solve the underlying problem, which is the most important (if OP allows external library to be added)

Comment: I don't usually upvote "Use this library to solve this simple task" responses but in this case I think Moment would be a huge improvement over OPs clever code.  Also moment is basically the industry standard for manipulating time with .js.

Comment: Moment is normally a great solution but can't always work with external library.

Comment: @ErwinvanEkeren I don't really understand your comment. Can you use moment.js here or not ? If no, it would be helpful to edit your question and add this requirement.

Comment: @Pac0 sorry for the misunderstanding, I can't use an external library in this case, I edited the question!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in the assignment statement for time. The call to now.getMinutes() does not return minutes 1-9 as '01', '02', ..., it returns them as '1', '2', etc.

Comment: actually, it returns a *number* (using quotes like you did could be ambiguous and give the impression it is a string)